# classes not running in a chronological order

Tags: python, tkinter

when i run the code it should start off by running the tkinter login system and then when you signup opens a menu system. this part worked fine until i made it so when you press the easy button on the menu system it should run the depth sesarch algorithm to generate the maze however when i added the class cells to gererate the maze it stopped running my login system and now just runs the code to generate the maze

i expected it to start off by runing the login system and when you signup load the menu(i tested this seperatly it works)and then when the easy button is pressed it opens the pygame window and generates the maze.

```
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3
from tkinter import messagebox
import pygame
from maze_generator import *
# Set up the database
conn = sqlite3.connect("users.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (username text, password text)")
conn.commit()

# Define the password validation regex


# Define the LoginWindow class
class LoginWindow(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Login")
        self.geometry("300x200")

        # Create the widgets
        self.username_label = tk.Label(self, text="Username:")
        self.username_entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.password_label = tk.Label(self, text="Password:")
        self.password_entry = tk.Entry(self, show="*")
        self.login_button = tk.Button(self, text="Login", command=self.login)
        self.signup_button = tk.Button(self, text="Sign Up", command=self.signup)

        # Place the widgets
        self.username_label.place(x=10, y=10)
        self.username_entry.place(x=80, y=10)
        self.password_label.place(x=10, y=40)
        self.password_entry.place(x=80, y=40)
        self.login_button.place(x=10, y=70)
        self.signup_button.place(x=80, y=70)

    def login(self):
        # Get the username and password
        username = self.username_entry.get()
        password = self.password_entry.get()

        # Check the credentials against the database
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?", (username, password))
        user = cursor.fetchone()
        if user:
            # If the credentials are valid, show a success message
            tk.messagebox.showinfo("Success", "You have logged in successfully.")
        else:
                       # If the credentials are invalid, show an error message
            tk.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Invalid username or password.")

    def signup(self):
        # Get the username and password
        username = self.username_entry.get()
        password = self.password_entry.get()

        # Validate the password
       
        has_upper = False
        has_lower = False

        for char in password:
            if char.isupper():
                has_upper = True
            elif char.islower():
                has_lower = True
        
        has_number = False

        for char in password:
            if char.isdigit():
                has_number = True
            

        if len(password) < 8 or has_upper == False or has_lower == False or has_number == False:
            # If the password is invalid, show an error message
            tk.messagebox.showerror("Error", "The password must contain at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, and must be at least 8 characters long.")
            return

        # Check if the username is already taken
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?", (username,))
        user = cursor.fetchone()
        if user:
            # If the username is taken, show an error message
            tk.messagebox.showerror("Error", "This username is already taken.")
        else:
            # If the username is not taken, add the user to the database and show a success message
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?)", (username, password))
            conn.commit()
            # tk.messagebox.showinfo("Success", "You have signed up successfully.")
            LoginWindow.destroy(self)
            # Initialize Pygame and open the Pygame window
            pygame.init()
            WINDOW_SIZE = (400, 400)

            # Create the window and set the caption
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE)
            pygame.display.set_caption("Pygame Example")

            # Define colors
            BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
            WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

# Create rectangles for the buttons
            easy_button = pygame.Rect(50, 50, 100, 50)
            medium_button = pygame.Rect(150, 50, 100, 50)
            hard_button = pygame.Rect(250, 50, 100, 50)
            scoreboard_button = pygame.Rect(50, 150, 300, 50)

            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, easy_button)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, medium_button)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, hard_button)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, scoreboard_button)
            # Set up the font for the buttons
            font = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)
            
            easy_text = font.render("Easy", True, BLACK)
            medium_text = font.render("Medium", True, BLACK)
            hard_text = font.render("Hard", True, BLACK)
            scoreboard_text = font.render("Scoreboard", True, BLACK)

                # Position the text on the buttons
            screen.blit(easy_text, (easy_button.x + 25, easy_button.y + 10))
            screen.blit(medium_text, (medium_button.x + 20, medium_button.y + 10))
            screen.blit(hard_text, (hard_button.x + 25, hard_button.y + 10))
            screen.blit(scoreboard_text, (scoreboard_button.x + 60, scoreboard_button.y + 10))

                # Update the display
            pygame.display.update()

            # Main game loop
            # Main game loop
            running = True
            while running:
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        running = False
                    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                        # Get the mouse coordinates
                        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                        # Check if the easy button was pressed
                        if easy_button.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                            RES = WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1202, 600
                            TILE = 10
                            cols, rows = WIDTH // TILE, HEIGHT // TILE

                            pygame.init()
                            sc = pygame.display.set_mode(RES)
                            clock = pygame.time.Clock()

                            class Cell:
                                def __init__(self, x, y):
                                    self.x, self.y = x, y
                                    self.walls = {'top': True, 'right': True, 'bottom': True, 'left': True}
                                    self.visited = False

                                def draw_current_cell(self):
                                    x, y = self.x * TILE,self.y * TILE
                                    pygame.draw.rect(sc, pygame.Color('saddlebrown'), (x + 2, y + 2, TILE - 2, TILE - 2))    

                                def draw(self, sc):
                                    x, y = self.x * TILE, self.y * TILE
                                    if self.visited:
                                        pygame.draw.rect(sc,pygame.Color('black'), (x, y, TILE, TILE))

                                    if self.walls['top']:
                                        pygame.draw.line(sc, pygame.Color('darkorange'), (x, y), (x + TILE, y), 2)
                                    if self.walls['right']:
                                        pygame.draw.line(sc, pygame.Color('darkorange'), (x + TILE, y), (x + TILE, y + TILE), 2)
                                    if self.walls['bottom']:
                                        pygame.draw.line(sc, pygame.Color('darkorange'), (x + TILE, y + TILE), (x , y + TILE), 2)
                                    if self.walls['left']:
                                        pygame.draw.line(sc, pygame.Color('darkorange'), (x, y + TILE), (x, y), 2)
    
                                def check_cell(self, x, y):
                                    find_index = lambda x, y: x + y * cols
                                    if x < 0 or x > cols - 1 or y < 0 or y > rows - 1:
                                        return False
                                    return grid_cells[find_index(x, y)]

                                def check_neighbors(self):
        
                                    neighbors = []
                                    top = self.check_cell(self.x, self.y - 1)
                                    right = self.check_cell(self.x + 1, self.y)
                                    bottom = self.check_cell(self.x, self.y + 1)
                                    left = self.check_cell(self.x - 1, self.y)
                                    if top and not top.visited:
                                        neighbors.append(top)
                                    if right and not right.visited:
                                        neighbors.append(right)
                                    if bottom and not bottom.visited:
                                        neighbors.append(bottom)
                                    if left and not left.visited:
                                        neighbors.append(left)
                                    return choice(neighbors) if neighbors else False

                            def remove_walls(current, next):
                                dx = current.x - next.x
                                if dx == 1:
                                    current.walls['left'] = False
                                    next.walls['right'] = False
                                elif dx == -1:
                                    current.walls['right'] = False
                                    next.walls['left'] = False
                                    dy = current.y - next.y
                                if dy == 1:
                                    current.walls['top'] = False
                                    next.walls['bottom'] = False
                                elif dy == -1:
                                    current.walls['bottom'] = False
                                    next.walls['top'] = False

                            grid_cells = [Cell(col, row) for row in range(rows) for col in range(cols)]
                            current_cell = grid_cells[0]
                            stack = []

                            while True:
                                sc.fill(pygame.Color('darkslategray'))

                                for event in pygame.event.get():
                                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                                        exit()
                                [cell.draw(sc) for cell in grid_cells]
                                current_cell.visited = True
                                current_cell.draw_current_cell()
    
                                next_cell = current_cell.check_neighbors()
                                if next_cell:
                                    next_cell.visited = True
                                    stack.append(current_cell)
                                    remove_walls(current_cell, next_cell)
                                    current_cell = next_cell
                                elif stack:
                                    current_cell = stack.pop()
    

    
                                pygame.display.flip()
                                clock.tick(20)
window = LoginWindow().mainloop()
```

Comment: See [ask]. Post a [mre] with debugging details. Anyway, why not call PyGame API after LoginWindow().mainloop() returns? It's not a good idea to do that while the tkinter is looping.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).